# Is there a way to copy/paste data & limit the attribution to match the attribution in the Target Data Set?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, spatial-database, editing

In an effort to avoid digitizing, I want to copy specific watercbodies from a provincial database (shapefile format) and paste it to my taget layer, which are waterbodies significant to my project.  I don't want all the columns of attribution to paste over to my target data set (ie - I don't need the "GUT_NUMBER" column in my DBase).  Is my best approach to simply delete the attribute columns I don't want when I'm done, or is there a better/more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a feature class (or a shapefile) of with only the fields you want to keep. The field have to be the same name and data type.
- Add both the source and the target to ArcMap.
- Start Editing (Make sure you are in Data View)
- Select source polygons & copy
- Paste

Comment: Thanks Jakub (and +1) - I actually tested this exact same approach & it worked (before reading your answer).  I wasn't sure it would work, but my target set only kept the attribution I wanted. I selected your answer nonetheless since you took the time to post it for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two approaches:

Method1 : In ArcCatalog, right-click the feature class and select "Load Data". There you can select which fields you do not want to load.

[image]

Method 2: From ArMap, from toolboxes, select Data Management Tools -> Append. This also gives you a similar solution.

Comment: +1 Just for taking the time to post an answer (and thanks as well).  I used the method posted by Jakub (above) before I even read his answer.  It's very efficient so I'm just going to go with that methodology.